# jStorage not persisting keys in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

I can't get IE9 persist keys written by jStorage (the engine used being userData) (jQuery).

The write/read (all-in-one) seems to work properly ; the getter function retrieves the correct value :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery-json.js"></script>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jstorage.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert ("Localstorage support : " + $.jStorage.storageAvailable() );

        alert ('Setting bar -> aaa');
        $.jStorage.set('bar', 'aaa');

        alert ('Setting foo -> bbb');
        $.jStorage.set('foo', 'bbb');

        var foo = $.jStorage.get('foo')
        alert ('Getting foo =' + foo );

        alert ( "index = " + $.jStorage.index() );

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I use the following to just retrieve the value, the index is empty and foo is null :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery-json.js"></script>
    <script   type="text/javascript" src="jstorage.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        alert ("Localstorage support : " + $.jStorage.storageAvailable() );
        var foo = $.jStorage.get('foo');
        alert ('Getting foo =' + foo );

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't use any webserver, the files are loaded directly from the filesystem (and I *do not want* to use any webserver).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try building the string outside the method:
var msg = "Localstorage support : " + $.jStorage.storageAvailable();
alert ( msg );